# What does the notation "$\;(f·g)(x)\;$" mean?

Tags: functions, notation

Suppose I have two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. What does it mean to have $(f·g)(x)$?

This notation can be found in a [paper on Partial Differential Equations and Image Processing](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cGzO2aIZsfyz87_Np0ppEwadYL0mTS9h/view?usp=sharing):

> What we call a multiscale analysis is a family of transforms $(T_t)_{t>0}$ of an image $u^o(x)$, such that $u(t,x) = (T_t \cdot u^o)(x)$ can be seen as the image $u^o$ at a coarser scale $t$.

Comment: Do you mean $(f\circ g)(x)$?

Comment: @AndrewChin Are those diferent?

Comment: $\cdot$ denotes multiplication, but I cannot be sure you mean $(f\times g)(x)$.

Comment: If $f,g$ take on values in the real numbers (or in some structure where you can multiply two elements) then $f\cdot g$ might refer to the product which is again a function (on the same source) defined by $(f\cdot g)(x)=f(x)\cdot g(x)$

Comment: @AndrewChin It is shown in this paper I was reading https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cGzO2aIZsfyz87_Np0ppEwadYL0mTS9h/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Are you going to tell us where in the paper it is or do you expect that we read it all?

Comment: Sorry. On the section 1, parragraph 2, where it says multiscale analysis is a family of transforms...

Comment: I edited your question to include a link and an excerpt from the paper where I found the notation.  I expect that the $\cdot$ used here denotes multiplication.

Comment: @AndrewChin Thank you!

Comment: It seems that $T_t$ acts on functions and the action is denoted by $\cdot$ here. (So you can think of it as $T_t(u^0)$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with functions there are several standard notations that you should have always present:

The $\cdot$ is used to describe the usual product (sometimes called **pointwise product**):$$f(x)\cdot g(x)=f(x)g(x).$$
You can also **compose** both functions using $\circ$ in the following way:$$f\circ g = f(x)\circ g(x)=f(g(x)).$$
Finally, the notation used in the paper you mentioned, has to do with the **convolution**. The symbol $*$ is used to express the convolution of $f$ with $g$ (it is read this way), and it is defined in the following way:$$f*g(x)=(f*g)(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(\xi)g(x-\xi)d\xi.$$ This operation is closely related to the notion of Fourier transform and very popular in the real analysis, signal processing and differential equations fields.

Comment: @Arroz_con_Tomate The syntax $f(x) \circ g(x)＝f(g(x))$ is very dubious and unpleasant. Is one composing the maps $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ or is one composing $f$ with $g$ and evaluating this at $x$?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ To be more accurate, if $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to Z$, then, if we call $h=f\circ g$ and $g(x_0)=x_0$, we have that $h:X\to Z$ and $h(x_0)=f(g_0)$ $\forall x_0\in X$. You are doing both, compsing the maps and evaluating $f$ at $g(x)$. Ce sure to check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition for more info.

Answer (score 1):

In the most general setting, considering an arbitrary set $A$, a magma $(M, \cdot)$ -- which is a structure obtained by equipping the arbitrary set $M$ with an arbitrary binary operation $\cdot \colon M \times M \to M$ -- and two maps $f, g \colon A \to M$ one can define the *product* of the two maps as the map given by:
$$\begin{align}
fg \colon A &\to M \\
\left(fg \right)(x)&＝f(x)g(x),
\end{align}$$
where the product mentioned on the right-hand side of the second line refers of course to the binary operation $\cdot$ on $M$.

If one considers the *diagonal* direct product:
$$\begin{align}
f \underline{\times} g \colon A &\to M \times M \\
\left(f \underline{\times} g \right)(x)&＝\left(f(x), g(x)\right),
\end{align}$$
then we have the relation $fg＝\cdot \circ \left(f \underline{\times} g\right)$ expressing the product with respect to the diagonal direct product and the original underlying multiplication.

**P.S.** Upon closer inspection it seems that the notation used in the article you are referring to has nothing to do with the algebraic construction described above and is most likely an example of vaguely and sloppily used syntax, a custom which to the disappointment of some has become quite widespread nowadays...

Comment: It's not that sloppy (at least if one defines what these $T_i$ are, this was sloppy in the paper). There is a good category theoretical reason why one may write $fx$ instead of $f(x)$ if one considers $x$ via the notion of a generalized element.

Comment: @Qi Zhu The lack of any precise and rigorous definition of the syntax implemented is what makes the article sloppy in its presentation. With the notion that one can write $fx$ rather than $f(x)$ I fully agree, as it is a syntactical custom tipically encountered whenever a set (perhaps endowed with additional structure) acts on another set (again, potentially equipped with additional structure).

Comment: Yes, I agree. As for the notation, while your explanation is OK, i was referring to let $f : A \to B$ be any morphism in a category $\mathscr C$ and $x :  \ast \to A$ be a generalized element (in our case, $\mathscr C$ is something like $\mathbf{Set}$ and $*$ is the initial object with $x$ being the unique morphism corresponding to the element $x$), then one can really consider $f(x)$ as the composition $fx := f \circ x$.